# Unable to run localhost:3000 (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, localhost

I've found some related posts to mine... but none of the existing answers worked... so here is a new one from a Newbee :

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 and tried to install Ruby on rails following the various tutorials (http://rubyonrails.org/download), I even tried RVM... and so finally when I try to launch my server my localhost:3000 is not working.

Here is my terminal when I launch server :

```
laslo@ubuntu:~$ rails s
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/railties/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
      exists  
      exists  app/controllers
      exists  app/helpers
      exists  app/models
      exists  app/views/layouts
      exists  config/environments
      exists  config/initializers
      exists  config/locales
      exists  db
      exists  doc
      exists  lib
      exists  lib/tasks
      exists  log
      exists  public/images
      exists  public/javascripts
      exists  public/stylesheets
      exists  script/performance
      exists  test/fixtures
      exists  test/functional
      exists  test/integration
      exists  test/performance
      exists  test/unit
      exists  vendor
      exists  vendor/plugins
      exists  tmp/sessions
      exists  tmp/sockets
      exists  tmp/cache
      exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  db/seeds.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
       force  config/initializers/session_store.rb
overwrite config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
       force  config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
   identical  script/about
   identical  script/console
   identical  script/dbconsole
   identical  script/destroy
   identical  script/generate
   identical  script/runner
   identical  script/server
   identical  script/plugin
   identical  script/performance/benchmarker
   identical  script/performance/profiler
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
   identical  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/index.html
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/robots.txt
   identical  public/images/rails.png
   identical  public/javascripts/prototype.js
   identical  public/javascripts/effects.js
   identical  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
   identical  public/javascripts/controls.js
   identical  public/javascripts/application.js
   identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
   identical  log/server.log
   identical  log/production.log
   identical  log/development.log
   identical  log/test.log
      exists  vendor/rails
```

Any idea? Sure I'm missing something huge... but what?

Comment: it looks like it's creating a new app. can you try `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: Where are you? Are you in the project root?  `pwd` please

Comment: you might be using Rails 2, which is creating new project with that command.

Comment: Very good point.  In that case do `script/server`

Comment: you are really quick...thank you . Here are my answers : laslo@ubuntu:~$ bundle exec rails s
Could not locate Gemfile
laslo@ubuntu:~$ ls
Bureau            Images   new          rubygems-2.0.3  Téléchargements
Documents         Modèles  Public       s               Ubuntu One
examples.desktop  Musique  requirement  server          Vidéos
laslo@ubuntu:~$ script/server
bash: script/server: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
laslo@ubuntu:~$ pwd
/home/laslo
laslo@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Ok here we are... when I go in s/ and execute your command (Ruby 2) it works... now, 1) why am I in Rails 2 instead of 3 2) how can I update to 3

Comment: for info : laslo@ubuntu:~$ gem update rails
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
laslo@ubuntu:~/s$ gem --version
1.8.23

Comment: Any idea on how to upgrade from my rail 2 to 3? It seems that we are now reaching rail 4... am I completely outdated - if so why, as I performed the standard installation? Last but not least, is higher always better (3>2, 4>3 etc...) - what would you recommend (newbee)?

Comment: See my answer for info about version.  Also if you are finding my answer helpful please give me (and others) upvotes on our answers :)

Comment: Hi; see my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails server is for specific app. You started rails sever in root path, of course that won't work.

You need to create a new app at first.

```
$ rails new myapp
$ cd myapp
# Install the gems needed at first
$ bundle install
# Then start server
$ rails s
```

**Add**

From your code I found the real reason is you are using Ruby 1.9.1. This version is not supported by latest Rails which you just downloaded.

Try upgrade Ruby to 1.9.3 at least.

Comment: Sorry... not sure as I was doing it from my ~/. But thank you for your quick answer. When I perform your 1st command I get the same message as previous with no folder created

Answer (score 0):

### Rails 3+

Try `bundle exec script/rails server` from the project root.

e.g.

```
durrantm.../linker$ bundle exec script/rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-04-08 21:48:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-08 21:48:24] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-11-10) [i686-linux]
[2013-04-08 21:48:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9187 port=3000
```

### Rails 2

From the project root:

```
$ script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-04-08 21:58:11] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-04-08 21:58:11] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-11-10) [i686-linux]
[2013-04-08 21:58:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=10473 port=3000
```

If that fails, perhaps start again with:

```
cd                  # Go to your home directory
rails new abc       # Create the app
cd abc              # cd into the project's directory.
                    # Change the config/database.yml if desired.
script/rails server # for rails 3 or use the rails 2 command above.
```

More version info:

Ruby, you should be on 1.9.2+  Most folks are on 1.9.3+  now.
I recommend you use RVM to maintain your ruby versions.  Others also use rbenv.

rvm: https://rvm.io/ # Yes that is a real URL!
rbenv: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/

Rails you should be on rails 3.1+  Check with `rails -v`
You can install a newer version with `gem install rails` use `-v 3.1.2` to specify that version.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer but unfortunately get the same "could not locate Gemfile".

Comment: See additional info in my answer.

Comment: still have issues. laslo@ubuntu:~/s$ sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.11
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Rails version: 2.3.14

Comment: I even tried to start from scratch (uninstall rvm, ruby and rails and start over... but still same problem)

Comment: Please note that for 1.8 the -dev package is needed, not just ruby1.8-dev. So if you have ruby1.9.1 do `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev`

Comment: You're welcome.  Feel free to accept (the big check mark) and/or upvote my answer if it meets your need and/or is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

what is version of your Ruby?`Ruby-v` shows it?you shoud  do at the first these commands.

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

Comment: what is your gemfile of your project?is it's packages updated?do you bundle install successfully?

Comment: My ruby version is 1.9.3p194(2012-04-20 revision 35410){x86_64-linux]. When i perform bundle update i Get "could not locate Gemfile".

Comment: you may run command in other directory that your Gemfile is located.

Comment: rails2 has no Gemfile, that's all done in environments/development.rb, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with u and this is how I solved this.
Type *script/server* IN the cd of your project created.
I